# Finding an upper bound for the ratio of two Gaussian measures $ \frac{\gamma(U+m)}{\gamma(U)}$

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $\gamma$ is the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e.
$$
\gamma(E) = \int_E \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-0.5|x|^2} dx.
$$

Let $m \in \mathbb{R}$ be a fixed constant and $U$ an arbitrary open set. Can we find an upper bound for the ratio
$$
\frac{\gamma(U+m)}{\gamma(U)},
$$
i.e. is this ratio bounded by a constant which is independent of the set $U$?

Answer (score 1):

No, unless $m=0$.  Note that the ratio of densities

$$ \frac{f(x+m)}{f(x)} = e^{-xm - m^2/2}$$
can be arbitrarily large (as $x \to -\infty$ if $m > 0$, or $x \to +\infty$ if $m < 0$).  If $m > 0$ you take $U \subset (-\infty, -N)$ for large $N$, if $m < 0$ you take $U \subset (N, \infty)$, and get
$$ \frac{\gamma(U+m)}{\gamma(U)} > e^{N|m| - m^2/2}$$

Comment: excellent answer, let me add that the key here is the square in the exponential

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) The only thing I don't see is how some knowledge of the ratio of densities implies a bound for the ratio of measures. Or in other words: Can we describe the ration of measures in terms of the ratio of densities?

Comment: If $f_1(x) \le c f_2(x)$ on $U$, then $\int_U f_1(x)\; dx \le c \int_U f_2(x)\; dx$